How to extract dates from a string type column and load into 2 different datetime columns in SQL Server?
I have a SQL Server table as shown here:
CREATE TABLE #src 
(
    ID int,
    Descr varchar(500)
)

INSERT INTO #src (ID, Descr) VALUES (1, 'Test abc - May 2022 to April 2023')
INSERT INTO #src (ID, Descr) VALUES (2, 'abc - Apr 2020 to March 2021')
INSERT INTO #src (ID, Descr) VALUES (3, 'dyx - May 2023 to April 2024')

SELECT * FROM #src

I have a target table like this:
CREATE TABLE #tdt 
(
    ID int,
    Descr varchar(500),
    Prevdate datetime,
    Postdate datetime
)

SELECT * FROM #tdt

I do expect output like below



ID
Descr
Prevdate
Postdate




1
Test abc
May 2022
April 2023


2
abc
Apr 2020
March 2021


3
dyx
May 2023
April 2024



In order to get Descr values I did tried
SELECT
    *,
    LEFT(Descr, CHARINDEX('-', Descr) - 1)
FROM
    #src  

and it is working.
I need guidance in retrieving Prevdate and Postdate values from #src Descr column.
Thanks.

If they follow the same pattern, you can use the ' - ' and ' to ' to find the other parts.  Will it always be in that format?

Is 'April 2023' really a valid datetime value?

What is your SQL Server version (SELECT @@VERSION;)

Please try the following solution based on tokenization via the PARSENAME() function.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Descr VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Descr) VALUES 
('Test abc - May 2022 to April 2023'),
('abc - Apr 2020 to March 2021'),
('dyx - May 2023 to April 2024');

DECLARE @target TABLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Descr VARCHAR(500),
    Prevdate DATETIME,
    Postdate DATETIME
);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

INSERT @target (ID, Descr, Prevdate, Postdate)
SELECT t.* 
    , TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, PARSENAME(tokens, 2)) AS Prevdate
    , TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, PARSENAME(tokens, 1)) AS Postdate
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(Descr, '-', '.'),'to', '.')) AS t1(tokens);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @target;

Output



ID
Descr
Prevdate
Postdate




1
Test abc - May 2022 to April 2023
2022-05-01 00:00:00.000
2023-04-01 00:00:00.000


2
abc - Apr 2020 to March 2021
2020-04-01 00:00:00.000
2021-03-01 00:00:00.000


3
dyx - May 2023 to April 2024
2023-05-01 00:00:00.000
2024-04-01 00:00:00.000




This is great, I did not know you can split into tokens using a cross apply, how does that works

CROSS APPLY is not splitting anything. It just makes two REPLACE() calls. Just add tokens column to the SELECT clause to see its value. The PARSENAME() function does the actual split.

Now it all makes sense to me, this answer should be marked as the accepted

You can parse the values from the varchar column, but if you want to transform them into real datetime type you will have to dig some deeper
select t.descr,
       trim(left(t.dates, charindex('to', t.dates) - 1)) as prevdate,
       trim(substring(t.dates, charindex(' to ', t.dates) + 4, len(t.dates))) as postdate
from   ( select left(s.Descr, charindex('-', s.Descr) - 1) as descr,
                trim(right(s.Descr, len(Descr) - charindex('-', s.Descr))) as dates
         from   src s
       ) t


or all using substring
select substring(s.descr, 0, charindex(' - ', s.descr)) as descr,
       substring(s.descr, charindex(' - ', s.descr) + 3, len(s.descr) - charindex(' to ', s.descr) - 4) as prevdate,
       substring(s.descr, charindex(' to ', s.descr) + 4, len(s.descr)) as postdate
from   src s

You can experiment yourself in this fiddle



descr
prevdate
postdate




Test abc
May 2022
April 2023


abc
Apr 2020
March 2021


dyx
May 2023
April 2024




Just another option using JSON in concert with a CROSS APPLY.
Example
SELECT ID 
       ,Descr    = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
       ,PrevDate = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
       ,PostDate = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
 FROM  #src A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape(replace([Descr],' to ',' - '),'json'),' - ','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)

Results
ID  Descr       PrevDate    PostDate
1   Test abc    May 2022    April 2023
2   abc         Apr 2020    March 2021
3   dyx         May 2023    April 2024

